# Getting "Type argument is not within its bounds" for recursive bounds for defined in Java when calling it from Kotlin 1.7.x

Tags: kotlin

I'm working with an interface that is defined like this in Java:

```
public interface MyClass<T extends MyClass<T, D>, D> { .. }
```

In a Java class, `FindClassFromString`, there's a method that is defined like this:

```
public <D, T extends MyClass<T, D>> Class<T> findClassFromString(String type) {
    ...
}
```

In Java I can call this method like this:

```
var findClassFromString = new FindClassFromString();
Class<MyClass<?, ?>> clazz = (Class<MyClass<?, ?>>) findClassFromString.findClassFromString("SomeString");
```

I do get a warning that says that the cast is unchecked, but that's fine.

What I need to do is to call the `findClassFromString` from Kotlin. This used to work in Kotlin 1.6.21:

```
val clazz = findClassFromString.findClassFromString<Any, MyClass<*, *>>("SomeString") // clazz will have type Class<MyClass<*, *>>
```

I would get a warning, `UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED_WARNING`, which is OK. But after upgrading to 1.7+, I get a compile-time error instead:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected: MyClass<MyClass<*, *>!, TypeVariable(D)!>!
Found:    MyClass<*, *>!

Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected: Nothing!
Found:    Any!
```

How can I make the Kotlin code compile with Kotlin 1.7+?

Comment: Is the usage of the recursively typed Java class within your control, i.e. could you also define and use a subtype of it instead of that specific class?

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to obtain some `Class<MyClass<*, D>>` for some type `D`, it might help to define a helper class in Java, because Java does not care as much for the type as Kotlin does:

```
public class FindClassWorkaround {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <D> Class<MyClass<?, D>> findClassFromString(String type) {
        var findClassFromString = new FindClassFromString();
        return (Class<MyClass<?, D>>) findClassFromString.findClassFromString(type);
    }
}
```

Then you can call that helper class in Kotlin without the need to specify a recursive type:

```
    val clazz = FindClassWorkaround.findClassFromString<Any>("SomeString")
```

The variable `clazz` will have type `Class<MyClass<*, Any>>`.

Comment: Yeah this is what I do currently, but I was hoping for a Kotlin-only solution.